how do i make a String.split() stop after a certain spot?
so i have been trying to do this exercise for programming class, where basically you have to split the string at the empty spaces.
the string is: 4157245.8043 671332.0498 4774713.5642 APPROX POSITION XYZ
a lot of people in my class did it while defining substrings based on positions, basically with indexes from x to y, which i dont want to do, since as soon as something changes in the string, your entire program isnt going to work properly
now my problem is that while the coordinates get separated well, the text that comes after also gets separated in different parts, making my output:
part 1: 4157245.8043
part 2: 671332.0498
part 3: 4774713.5642
part 4: APPROX
part 5: POSITION
part 6: XYZ

how can i make the programm exclude that part of the string in this case? i would say id have to initiate an array that counts up with each space that comes up, but i dont know how to implement it right now and have been struggling for a while with this.
here is my code as of now:
public class test7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = " 4157245.8043 671332.0498 4774713.5642 APPROX POSITION XYZ ";
        String[] rrr = s.split("\\s+");
        
        //System.out.println("Dieser Satellit befindet sich über [] in der Höhe von []");
        for (int i=1; i<s.length(); i++) {
            
            System.out.println("part " + ((i+1)-1) + ": " + rrr[i]);
        }
        
    }

thanks in advance :D
i tried implementing an array that counts up in the for loop, but i mustve been doing it wrong for it didnt work properly

Please [edit] your question to include the result you do want.

Also, you may be interested in the two-arguments version of split.

Split on spaces to tokenize, then take the first 3 tokens? Arrays.copyOf(rrr, 3)

What is the expected output you are looking for? That part isn't clear.

You could use a regular expression
Note that

[^ ]+ matches not-a-space-character one or more times
.+ matches any character one or more times
(...) is a capturing gorup

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) (.+) ");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(" 4157245.8043 671332.0498 4774713.5642 APPROX POSITION XYZ ");
if (matcher.matches()) {
   String s1 = matcher.group(1); // 4157245.8043
   String s2 = matcher.group(2); // 671332.0498
   String s3 = matcher.group(3); // 4774713.5642
   String s4 = matcher.group(4); // APPROX POSITION XYZ
}


You can check if the string consists of letters as answered in this question: What is the best way to tell if a character is a letter or number in Java without using regexes?
Do this afterwards and then join the strings to one string, or you can check it before/get the space-positions and use substrings...

It all depends on whether the structure of the string can change or not.
If it doesn't change, i.e. it's always 3 coordinates followed by text
You could use split(regex, limit), e.g. String[] rrr = s.split("\\s+", 4); to get an array of at most 4 elements (3 coordinates + text).
If the number of coordinates and their position might change
Assuming you might get just 2 coordinates followed by the text or maybe more, then you'd need to split based on whether the space is preceded or succeeded by a coordinate.
For that, you'd first need to define what a coordinate looks like, e.g. \d+\.\d+ (means "at least 1 digit, dot, at least 1 digit"). Then add a look-ahead ("preceded") and look-behind ("succeeded") to the condition: (?<=\d+\.\d+)\s+|\s+(?=\d+\.\d+) (means "whitespace preceded by coordinate or whitespace succeeded by coordinate").
Finally, since Java regex doesn't like unbounded quantifiers in look-around expressions you might need to add a bounded one, e.g. (?<=\d{1,99}\.\d{1,99}) (means "1 to 99 digits, dot, 1 to 99 digits").
Using this you could split "POS: 1.23 X 2.34 Y 34.567 Z APPROX POSITION OF 3 COORDS" into ["POS:", "1.23", "X", "2.34", "Y", "34.567", "Z APPROX POSITION OF 3 COORDS"]. Of course you'd now need additional logic to find the coordinates in that array (e.g. trying to parse the strings).
Alternatively use capturing groups as lance-java suggested. You could then either define the maximum number of coordinates in the regex (1 capturing group per potential coordinate) and try to get them - those not present would return null. However, the corresponding regex can be messed up quite easily.
Instead, you might want to search for the coordinates in a loop, e.g. like this:
String input = "POS: 1.23 X 2.34 Y 34.567 Z APPROX POSITION OF 3 COORDS";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

//keep searching
while(m.find()) {
  //when there is a match, group 1 contains the matching coordinate
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}

This would yield:
1.23
2.34
34.567

